# Cyclic decoposition group of an absolute value

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, absolute-value

Let $K\supset \mathbb Q$ a finite extension such that $G:=\operatorname{Gal}(K|\mathbb Q)=\mathbb F_{2^n}$, and let $w$ be an absolute value of $K$ extending a non-archimedean absolute value of  $\mathbb Q$.

Consider now the decomposition group of $w$:

$$
G_w:=\{\sigma\in G\colon w\circ\sigma=w\}
$$

Is it true that in this case $|G_w|\le 2$? One should show that $G_w$ is cyclic, but I don't know  how to proceed.

Comment: As a group $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ is just $(\Bbb{F}_2)^n$. It is true if $p$ is unramified. Otherwise no, try with $p = 2,K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt{-3})$. What is cyclic is the quotient of $G_w$ by inertia $I_w$.

Comment: I forgot to say we can take $n$ be large enough. So we are choosing $K$ such that $G=\mathbb F_{2^n}$ and $n$ large.

Comment: It doesn't change anything, try adapting my counter-example.